# What's going to drive me crazier? ViewState and PostBacks or MVC's learning curve?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crud

A hopefully somewhat simple question. I'm starting out in ASP.net development and I'm wondering what is going to ultimately drive me crazier when I encounter it?

Is it going to be ViewState and Postbacks coupled with the horrendous looking Page Life Cycle?

Or is it going to be door number 2, with MVC's steep learning curve, class method based URL-handling and generally more complex-seeming setup and use?

I'm looking to essentially build a large CRUD-based web application, if that's of any concern.

Comment: steep learning curve?  its pretty flat.

Comment: I've generally heard quite the opposite. Maybe you're a savant, I don't know, but the majority of developers out there comment that MVC has a very steep learning curve and Web Forms is much better suited to RAD (rapid application development)

Comment: Well, I am pretty awesome, not quite savant :-)  but I don't think Webforms is better for "RAD" ( hello 1990s software fashion! ).  It can be good for drag'n'drop programming. But quickly you have to get your hands dirty and do some real programming.   I think people who find MVC a steep learning curves are those coming from WebForms because it is different and you have to think differently about things, especially when it comes to state.

Comment: As far as I've understood, there is not a single drag'n'drop control in MVC.. is this the case?

Comment: I don't think so,  personally,  I tend to do a lot client side, so the MVC app mostly becomes a web api, and most things are done using javascript on the client side using things like knockout, coffeescript, sass, and then any other javascript toys as needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postbacks are far more confusing. MVC works the way HTTP works, so if you understand that then all you have left to learn is syntax and libraries.

OTOH, postbacks have poisoned a lot of people into some serious misunderstandings of how HTTP works...

Comment: Does an MVC for Beginners guide exist? I mean, almost every single guide I've seen really assumes a pretty deep set of knowledge. Web Forms tutorials/guides just seem easier to understand.. is MVC more for advanced/professional users (for lack of better terms)?

Comment: That's a really good question, and I don't know the answer. It kind of just clicked because I had been trying to shoehorn web forms into doing the same kind of thing, but I suppose I mostly learned it by reading a bunch of little blog postings and articles as it was coming out. I'm not sure where there is a good ab initio tutorial.

Comment: Web Forms are pretty much designed to require very little knowledge of how things work and what's actually going on behind the scenes. MVC on the other hand, is just a framework, and requires a certain level of understanding of how things work on the web to actually put it to use. That's not a bad thing though. Web Forms are crippling. Spend some time reading up on HTTP and REST, even TCP/IP itself if you're feeling brave. It will change the way you look at the web, and help you be a better web developer.